# Off-canvas menu turn off animation on slide based on condition

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

Currently I am working on a project that is similar to this example:

[Off Canvas Menu Example](http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/emwBey)

HTML:

```
 <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">

    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle" href="#" >Menu</a>

    <!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <!-- whatever you want goes here -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        ...
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <!-- main content goes here -->
    <p>Set in the year 0 F.E. ("Foundation Era"), The Psychohistorians opens on Trantor, the capital of the 12,000-year-old Galactic Empire. Though the empire appears stable and powerful, it is slowly decaying in ways that parallel the decline of the Western Roman Empire. Hari Seldon, a mathematician and psychologist, has developed psychohistory, a new field of science and psychology that equates all possibilities in large societies to mathematics, allowing for the prediction of future events.</p>

  <!-- close the off-canvas menu -->
  <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .left-off-canvas-menu {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).foundation();

$('.off-canvas-wrap').foundation('offcanvas', 'show', 'move-right');
$('.off-canvas-wrap').foundation('offcanvas', 'hide', 'move-right');
$('.off-canvas-wrap').foundation('offcanvas', 'toggle', 'move-right');
```

I am using off-canvas to show a menu on page. however based on some condition I like to turn off animation and just the menu pops in without any animation and then turn the animation on later based on some other conditions?

Would that be possible ?